# JavaScript reset event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
<a id="LoadButton">load</a>
    $('#LoadButton').click(function () {
        ...
        ...
    }).appendTo(div);
    $('<br/>').appendTo(div);
    });

    $("#leftGrid").append(div);
```

After click I append data into 'leftGrid' div.

Everything works great! The problem is that if you will click twice on the load link button the data will be append twice... 3 clicks will append 3 times... how can I set the link button to reset the div before every load?

Comment: Take some time and provide well formatted code in your questions.

Comment: people its not code that was just an example of div,click event and append

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your `#leftGrid` a DIV?

Try

```
$("#leftGrid").html(div);
```

This is replace all html inside `#leftGrid` with the variable `div`'s valuables